# Newton's first law, unless + past participle

Tags: meaning, grammar, phrase-meaning, learning

I was reading Newton's first law:

> An object at rest stays at rest and an object in motion stays in
>   motion with the same speed and in the same direction unless acted upon
>   by an unbalanced force.

In the part:

> unless acted upon by an unbalanced force.

The meaning is clear (because I have already read this law in my native language) but I had never seen this construction:

```
unless + verb (pp)
```

Is this construction correct?

Also if you can explain all the grammar of this last part `(unless....)` I would appreciate it so much

Comment: This will not make sense unless understood as having a redundant *it is* elided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Unless* in this sense is a conjunction. (There is a prepositional sense too, but this is now rare).

Conjunctions of course join clauses, words or phrases.

> He went to the shops **and** he bought some milk.
>
> She wanted to go **but** she felt too ill.

It is common, and standard, with conjunctions to omit a subject common to both phrases joined:

> He went to the shops **and** bought some milk.
>
> She wanted to go **but** felt too ill.

When a copula is used, then the copula might also be omitted:

> The boat was built **and** it was launched.
>
> He was taken outside **and** he was shot.
>
> The boat was built **and** launched.
>
> He was taken outside **and** shot.

*Unless* is a subordinating conjunction (or *subordinator*) so it joins an independent and dependent clause:

> An object will remain at rest or in motion at constant velocity **unless** it is acted upon by an unbalanced force.

The omission of the subject *it* and the copula *is* can happen here just as with any other conjunction:

> An object will remain at rest or in motion at constant velocity **unless** acted upon by an unbalanced force.

As can be seen, it is just another example of this normal omission that happens with conjunctions.

Answer (score 4):

In this context, the phrase

> unless acted upon by an unbalanced force.

can be thought of as a short-hand notation for

> unless [the object is] acted upon by an unbalanced force.

You will see a similar type of shortened speech in an American legal context. They do it for the sake of brevity.

Comment: Should not be *unless [it is] acted upon by an unbalanced force.* instead?

Comment: That's fine too. In this case, the word "it" refers to "the object". And you're right, I should have used present tense ("is" rather than "has been"). I will change my answer accordingly.

Comment: It's not "a shorthand notation", and certainly not legalese as the last paragraph suggests, it's perfectly standard and grammatical English.

Comment: Yes, it's a regular rule that deletes repeated subjects and auxiliary forms of _be_ in subordinate clauses with participial predicates (_acted upon, acting upon_). Shorthand is a form of writing, which represents speech, not the other way around.